# how to take care of form closing and server signout?

Tags: c#, c++

So I have C++ server and C# client (GUI)

I have 7 forms and when I close any form the client does not disconnect from the server (the client needs to send msg to the server that says that he wants to sign out/exit).

I have tried adding the `Form_Closing` event but there's a lot of situations where a form is being closed not by the user and by the program and the `Form_Closing` and the user signs out even though he is still in the program.

So my question is

- Is there is a fix for this?  Adding Form_Closing event to every form is long and most likely won't solve the problem or would solve it but take a lot of time.

I was wondering if there is an event to see if it's the user closing (by the **X** button  or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or by Task Manager or by the user somehow...)

I'm sure this is a known problem - to sign out the client from the server when they exit the GUI by force.

Comment: That is pretty vague, you don't give us a good handle on *exactly* when the client should disconnect.  Consider writing an event handler for the Application::Exit event.  And you probably ought to do something about unexpected crashes, depends, writing an event handler for the AppDomain::CurrentDomain::UnhandledException event is never really optional since you also need to provide a good diagnostic.  It will never be perfect, no sign-out when you trip over the power cord or terminate the program while debugging or kill it with Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out why your form is being closed by accessing the [`CloseReason`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason?view=netframework-4.7.2) of your `FormClosingEventArgs` parameter:

```
private void Form_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
        ; // Do something in this case
}
```

It's worth reading the documentation on this enum to find out the finder details. I would suggest though, that it is impossible to catch every reason your app might be closed, for example if the process is ended ('killed') by the user, you will get no warning, the process will simple end. It would be better to design things so that the server closes any sessions it might keep after a timeout period.